# Matlab warnings, replace character with vector

Tags: matlab, warnings

I have an algorithm containing a loop. In the loop several calculations are done and a warning is issued for some border cases. Rather than having the warning show up each time, i would like to have a warning after the loop containing all the indices of the loop where something went wrong.

So instead of

```
for j=1:T
    warning('Something went wrong for j = %d',j)
end
```

I would like to have

```
for j=1:T
   ...
end
warning('Something went wrong for j = %d',IndicesOfJ)
```

Now I tried

```
warning('Something went wrong for j = %d',[1,2])
```

But that just prints

```
Warning: Something went wrong for j = 1.Something went wrong for j = 45.
```

instead of

```
Warning: Something went wrong for j = 1 45.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
errflag = 0
% your loop. If warning criteria are met, set errflag to 1 and store the index.
if errflag
    warning('Something went wrong for j = %s',sprintf('%u ',IndicesOfJ));
end
```

For example:

```
IndicesOfJ = [1 3 4 5];
warning('Something went wrong for j = %s',sprintf('%u ',IndicesOfJ));
```

Returns

```
Warning: Something went wrong for j = 1 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
warning('Something went wrong for j = %s',mat2str(IndicesOfJ))
```

For example :

```
>> warning('Something went wrong for j = %s',mat2str([1,2]))
```

Would return :

```
Warning: Something went wrong for j = [1 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define error as

```
error = zeros(1,T);

for i = 1:T

  if condition is met

    error(i) = 1; 

  end

end

warning(['Something went wrong for j = ' num2str(find(error))])
```

This is a possible solution.